# Conditional layout of multiple divs in Thymeleaf

Tags: html, thymeleaf

I am struggling to format this div structure using `th:each` in Thymleaf. 
The desired html format is as follows

> Desired HTML

```
<div class="row interest-featured"> <!--Parent Div -->
   <div class="col-md-4 interest">
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-4 interest">
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-4 interest">
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-4 interest">
   </div>
</div>
<div class="row interest-featured"> <!--Parent Div -->
   <div class="col-md-4 interest">
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-4 interest">
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-4 interest">
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-4 interest">
   </div>
</div>
```

> Progress until now

```
<div th:each="interest,status : ${interest}" th:class="${(status.index + 1 % 3) == 0}? 'row interest-featured' :''">
   <div class="col-md-4 interest">
   </div>
</div>
```

Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks

PS: HTML texts are removed for brevity

Comment: And what isn't working? So your question is?

Comment: My question is how can i render the desired output  using thymeleaf iterator.

Comment: To me it looks like you want another `th:each` on the inner `<div>`, but without knowing your object structure we don't know on what you want to iterate.

Comment: I tried an inner loop on `interest` variable but its not working..

Comment: But what are you trying to achieve exactly? You want to make sure a row is created after every 3-4 items? Or you want to iterate on something specific? And what does your current progress lead to?

Comment: I have this `interest` list being served from the server. i want to iterate through this list and populate the divs accordingly. Now for the designs i have to loop three times inside the parent. One parent row --> Three child items. So all in all there are 4 parent divs with 3 childs each. Hope this makes sense. Let me know if you watn to know something else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I understand the issue here. If you have a flat list and you want to display it in a Bootstrap grid, you'll have to create new rows for each *n* elements.

The solution to this problem isn't as clean as a normal `th:each`, but you'll have to use it twice and have proper `th:if` statements on when you want to display it.

For example, for the `.row` element, you want to only show it for elements with index 0, 3, 6, ... (if you want a 1/3th column grid). This means you should do:

```
<div th:each="interest,rowStatus : ${interests}" class="row interest-featured" th:if="${rowStatus.index % 3} == 0">
</div>
```

Now, for the children of the row you'll have to iterate again over your collection, but filter it so that for the first row you only show elements with index 0-2 for the second row the elements 3-5, ... .

To do that you use another `th:if`:

```
<div th:each="interest,rowStatus : ${interests}" class="row interest-featured" th:if="${rowStatus.index % 3} == 0">
    <div th:each="interest,interestStatus : ${interests}" class="col-md-4 interest" th:text="${interest}"
         th:if="${interestStatus.index lt rowStatus.index + 3 and interestStatus.index ge rowStatus.index}"></div>
  </div>
```

---

If you don't want to use a cumbersome template like this, you can always just iterate over the column itself. If you're using Bootstrap, it will automatically create columns that do not fit within a row on a new line, for example:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">Column 1</div>
    <div class="col-md-4">Column 2</div>
    <div class="col-md-4">Column 3</div>
    <div class="col-md-4">Column 4</div><!-- This item will be on a new row because the grid does only allow 12 spaces -->
</div>
```

However, there are some differences between both approaches when the content of the column is variable in height.

---

> **NOTE**: You're also using the `interest` variable twice. The collection is named `${interest}`, but the result variable is also called `interest`. You probably have to rename one of those.

Comment: this looks quite promising. I will let you know if this works. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You use object.

html

```
<div class="source_list" th:each="history : ${historys}">
        <label>date : <span th:text="${history.date}">2016.06.27</span></label>
        <br /> 

        <label>description : </label><span th:text="${history.description}">2016.06.27</span>

        <br /> <br />
</div>
```

contorller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/settings/history/{companyIdx}")
public ModelAndView showHistory(ModelAndView mav, @PathVariable int companyIdx, HttpServletRequest request) {
    String language = CookieUtil.getCookieValue(request, "lang");
    Company company = companyService.findCompanyByIdx(companyIdx);

    List<CompanyHistory> historys = companyService.findHistoryByLanguage(company, language);


    mav.addObject("company", company);
    mav.addObject("historys", historys);

    mav.setViewName("/company/company_settings_history");

    return mav;
}
```

dto

```
@Entity(name = "company_history")
public class CompanyHistory {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int idx;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "company_id")
    private Company company;

    private String date;

    private String description;

    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks Urong for the answer. But this is not what i wanted.